# Show that ${\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-2x^2}} - 1-2x^2 = O(x^4)$ as $x \to 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, notation, solution-verification, asymptotics

This is my first time using Big-Oh notation and I just wanted to make sure I got this all correct. Please point out any errors, thank you!

First simplify $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-2x^2} - 1-2x^2$ to $f(x) = \frac{4x^4}{1-2x^2}$.

Observe that since $x\rightarrow 0$ we have that
\begin{equation*}
-1 < x < 1
\end{equation*}
which implies
\begin{equation*}
0 \leq 2x^2 < 2
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
-2 < -2x^2 \leq 0
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
-1 < 1-2x^2 \leq 1
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
0 \leq |1-2x^2| \leq 1
\end{equation*}
We can thus conclude that,
\begin{equation*}
|f(x)| = |\frac{4x^4}{1-2x^2}| = \frac{4x^4}{|1-2x^2|} \leq 4x^4
\end{equation*}

and $f(x) = O(x^4)$.

Comment: If $0 \leq |1-2x^2| \leq 1$, instead of $\frac{4x^4}{|1-2x^2|} \leq 4x^4$, you actually have that it's $\geq 4x^4$. Dividing by number smaller than 1 makes the result larger.

Comment: Show that $f(x) /x^4\to 4$ and conclude that $f(x) =O(x^4)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You want to bound the denominator from below. The denominator equals zero when $x=\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. Set some $c<\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. Then when $|x|\leq c$, it follows that $|1-2x^2|\geq 1-2c^2>0.$